# Understanding generic methods in Java

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm trying to understand a method which I read over in an existing Android app. The declaration of the method looks as follows:

```
protected <V, T extends Result> void postObject(final V input, final T result, final ConnectionTarget endpoint, final boolean restart, final int id, final LoaderProvider provider, final ServiceCallbacks<T> callbacks) {
```

I just read about generics, so I more or less understand what's going on here, but not exactly. Therefore I have two questions:

1. should `input` be a type (i.e. a class), or should it simply be an object of any type?
2. What does the `<V, T extends Result>` mean? As far as I understand that place should always describe the return type of the method, but it already says `void` behind it, plus, it says both `V` and `T`.

Could anybody give an example of how to call this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will split it in to smaller sections so that it is easier to understand.
In the section:

```
protected <V, T extends Result> void
```

the `<V, T extends Result>` is an optional section (normally isn't there) and is used for specifying generic types (or unknown object types).  This is designated by the `<` and `>` and that any comma separated value is a separate object (the object 'T' has to extend Result).

This means that later in the method call:

```
... postObject(final V input,...
```

that input is of the object type V, meaning that it can be any object you want.

**EDIT**

A basic example of calling this method would be:

```
//Now post it
postObject("my input object", null /*Your result class*/, null /*your endpoint*/, true, 0, null /*your loaderProvider*/, null /*your callbacks*/);
```

Comment: Alright, so as far as I understand, they are not parameters which should be supplied in that spot when calling the actual method, right? Could you give an example of how I could use/call this method?

Comment: Just one more thing; ConnectionTarget is an interface. Does that mean that the object that I put in there should implement the ConnectionTarget interface?

Comment: Correct.  Think of the ConnectionTarget methods as listeners for events.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to think of the `<V, T extends Result>` section of this method definition would be to think of this as a declaration of generic parameters that will be contained in the method signature itself. This definition allows you to ensure that your parameters are descended from a particular type (in your example `T` has to be a subclass of `Result`) and also allows your signature to not choke when `T` and `V` are referenced. As far as your questions are concerned:

1. `input` can simply be an object of any type
2. `<V, T extends Result>` simply means that you will have two generic parameters that are used in your method signature where any `V` parameter can be an Object of any type and any `T` parameter needs to be a subclass of `Result`